# Hazelcast setting in-memory-format on runtime when creating new map

Tags: hazelcast

I'm using Hazelcast in my project in conjunction with Hadoop. Hadoop is doing batch processing of data, while Hazelcast stores additional data which is accessed from jobs (lookups). The problem is that our queries by predicate work really slow on our cluster.

I would like to change in-memory-format to CACHED or setOptimizedQuery flag, to speed them up, but can I do this on working cluster? I know this can be done in config, but it's not really working for the project. This requires restarting cluster and works only for a map with a given name. We run a lot of hadoop jobs, each is processing the data for a particular date and location. The data is loaded for each hadoop job for the same date and location before we run the job. So we can have many maps with the same type of data and we distinguish them by map name (ie. CLIENTS_DATA_20141215_US)

We load a few maps with different objects which we get from data warehouse. Only for one map we use complex predicates to get the data so I would like to change the in-memory-format only for this particular map, when I create it and attempt to load the data.

Can this be done? Or maybe someone had simmilar problem and can suggest any solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the behavior of a map.

You can use wildcards

e.g. you could create 2 maps in your hazelcast.xml

```
<map name="objectmap-*">
    ...
</map>

<map name="binarymap-*">
   ...
</map>
```

PS: What kind of predicate do you use? Do you make use of the SQL predicate? If yes, consider making use of a manually written one. The SQL predicate is slow; we are going to address this under 3.5; but for the time being a manually written predicate is a lot faster.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I'm not using SQL queries, but Criteria API. This wildcard is a great suggestion. So I can do name="CLIENTS_DATA*" and each map I create which matches the pattern will have the specified properties like in-memory-format? Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: That is correct. So if you map is called CLIENTS_DATAfoobar, then it matches with CLIENTS_DATA*. So this way different maps can easily share the same configuration.

Comment: And this can be the solution for my case. Thank you very much :)

Comment: No problem. Somewhere on the roadmap there is support for on the fly configuration of data-structures.